# Can't properly create a maven project with Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, project

When i try and create a maven project with intellij https://ibb.co/ek7Lfv and the project has been created i can't create any java files? when ever i clikc on the folders https://ibb.co/c7DnSa this is what i get and no option for new java class file? What is happaning.

And then after roughly 10 mins of waiting i finally get this massage https://ibb.co/cPp5DF and then it starts working as it should. But why do i have to wait 10 min for it pop up?
What the heck am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ has unintuitive default behaviour for maven projects. It does not apply changes from `pom.xml` to project structure.

So every time I create or import maven project I manually select a checkbox [`Import Maven projects automatically`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-from-maven-page-1.html)

Comment: it seems to be working, so i figure you can't create a maven project inside of a maven project? I mean the same way you can for an example create a packege inside of a package and each packege can haven it's main class and it will work as it shoud

Comment: What you are talking about sounds like [maven modules](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html). Using this mechanism maven project can contain child maven modules. You can use `Create IntelliJ IDEA modules for aggregator projects (with 'pom' packaging)` checkbox in maven import settings - IntelliJ will show each module separately